# Call an html element and manipulate it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I am new to web development and am trying to implement a grid of file upload zones.

I am using [DropZone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com) for a site I am building. I have formatted DropZone and created additional DropZones in the html. I have four rows of four, creating a grid. Each of these are calling the same parent in the JavaScript. Inside each of these zones is a default message that says:

"Drop files here to Upload"

I would like to change this. In fact I would like each instance to have a separate description. Each zone in this grid would have a unique description.

What I would like to know is, how exactly would I go around doing this?

I have included the html for the site, the .js and .css for dropzone.js.

Would I be able to call an element from the html in JavaScript and have it manipulate `dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files here to upload",` from the javascript to create new text that would be relevant to the element being called?

The dropzones are all calling the same parent, I don't want to make sixteen different dropzone.js to make this work.

I am new to web development and an in-depth explanation would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

```js
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions = {
      url: null,
      method: "post",
      withCredentials: false,
      parallelUploads: 2,
      uploadMultiple: false,
      maxFilesize: 256,
      paramName: "file",
      createImageThumbnails: true,
      maxThumbnailFilesize: 10,
      thumbnailWidth: 120,
      thumbnailHeight: 120,
      filesizeBase: 1000,
      maxFiles: null,
      params: {},
      clickable: true,
      ignoreHiddenFiles: true,
      acceptedFiles: null,
      acceptedMimeTypes: null,
      autoProcessQueue: true,
      autoQueue: true,
      addRemoveLinks: false,
      previewsContainer: null,
      hiddenInputContainer: "body",
      capture: null,
      renameFilename: null,
      dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files here to upload",
      dictFallbackMessage: "Your browser does not support drag'n'drop file uploads.",
      dictFallbackText: "Please use the fallback form below to upload your files like in the olden days.",
      dictFileTooBig: "File is too big ({{filesize}}MiB). Max filesize: {{maxFilesize}}MiB.",
      dictInvalidFileType: "You can't upload files of this type.",
      dictResponseError: "Server responded with {{statusCode}} code.",
      dictCancelUpload: "Cancel upload",
      dictCancelUploadConfirmation: "Are you sure you want to cancel this upload?",
      dictRemoveFile: "Remove file",
      dictRemoveFileConfirmation: null,
      dictMaxFilesExceeded: "You can not upload any more files.",
      accept: function(file, done) {
        return done();
      },
```

```html
<title>Zone #16</title>

    <script src="/home/dan/Documents/YNGWork/Projects/FRANK/WebPage/DragDropWebUI/dropzone-4.3.0/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/dan/Documents/YNGWork/Projects/FRANK/WebPage/DragDropWebUI/dropzone-4.3.0/dist/dropzone.css">
    <p style="color:rgb(4,0,84)" align="center"> Drop your file in the appropriate zone. There are 16 zones to choose from </p>
    <!-- Change /upload-target to your upload address -->
    <form action="/home/dan/Documents/YNGWork/Projects/FRANK/WebPage/DragDropWebUI" class="dropzone"></form>


    <title>Zone #</title>

    <script src="/home/dan/Documents/YNGWork/Projects/FRANK/WebPage/DragDropWebUI/dropzone-4.3.0/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/dan/Documents/YNGWork/Projects/FRANK/WebPage/DragDropWebUI/dropzone-4.3.0/dist/dropzone.css">
    <!-- Change /upload-target to your upload address -->
    <form action="/home/dan/Documents/YNGWork/Projects/FRANK/WebPage/DragDropWebUI" class="dropzone"></form>
```

Comment: [Documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#tips) says "If you do not want the default message at all... you can put an element inside your dropzone element with the class `dz-message` and dropzone will not create the message for you." That might be helpful for specifying a custom message per zone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you only need to include the script and stylesheet once in the header. Just make sure if you put your script in the header, it's [with async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup).

**HTML**

```
<head>
<!-- Stylesheet goes here -->
<!-- Script goes here -->
</head>
```

Now for each of your forms, you need to give them a unique ID.This will let your JavaScript know which ID should get which box.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" class="dropzone" id="zone16"></form>
```

Finally, to give each zone a unique name, you only need to change the `dictDefaultMessage`.

You do this like so:

**JavaScript**

```
Dropzone.options.zone16 {
    dictDefaultMessage: "This is the sixteenth zone!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

defaultValues more looks like a backup of the configuration to set the default values back.

you can manipulate html(DOM) objects in javascript

first you have to get your object.

```js
//Via Id
var obj = document.getElementById("EnterIdHere");
//Via Class
var obj = document.getElementByClassName("EnterClassNameHere"); //unsure for correct spelling
```

Next you can access the DOM-Object and manipulate it.

```js
var obj = document.getElementById("divExample");

obj.style.backgroundColor = "green"; //Do a CSS action

obj.classList.toggle("Crap", false); //Disable CSS-Class Crap

obj.innerHTML = "New Content"; //Labeling it
```

Basic tutorial: http://callmenick.com/post/basics-javascript-dom-manipulation